# Best architecture for Kafka consumer

Tags: apache-kafka, architecture

I'm creating an application (web application) that needs to consume data (update client transactions) from a Kafka broker, but I'm not sure whats the best way to approach this.

I can think of three different scenarios to process each update:

1. Install the Kafka consumer directly in my app, then I can just start another instance of it (I'm using docker, so another container) and make the required updates there (I think this is the fastest one).
2. Create a separate service that consumes from Kafka and make the required updates in the app database. It seems to be pretty much the same as option 1, but a smaller app and more maintenance (2 apps instead of 1).
3. Create a separate service that consumes from Kafka and sends the updates to a REST endpoint in my app. It seems this would be a tiny service, very specific and the process remains in the app; but the app will receive more requests.

So, which are the pros/cons of each solution? Are all of them valid or some of them are a complete no? What drawbacks/risks should I be aware of?

I'm not looking just for a recommendation, I am more interested in understanding which solution works best for a given scenario.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With 3 you are splitting your application into multiple services. When you distribute your code across multiple services, you increase the level of indirection. The more indirection you have in your codebase, the harder it is for one person to work across the entire codebase because they have to keep more things in their head, and working across network boundaries requires a lot more code than working across files, and finally it's harder to debug across a network API.

Now, this doesn't mean that it's bad to split your application into multiple services. Doing so will help you scale your application as you can scale only the pieces that need scaling. Perhaps more importantly, splitting your application into multiple services makes it easier for more people to work on the codebase at the same time, since they have to adhere to the API contracts between the services, and are less likely to be working on the same files at the same time.

So 3 is a good choice if you have scaling issues, either for load on your application, or the number of developers that will work on it.

1 is a good choice if you want to move as quickly as possible and can put off scaling concerns for some time.

2 is the worst of both worlds. Your two services will be coupled by the database schema and will be sharing the same database instance. The separation of code means that you have extra indirection, the database schema coupling means that you won't fully get the people scaling benefits, and since most applications are bottlenecked by the database, the sharing of the db instance will deprive you of scaling independently for performance.

Comment: Great answer, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Personal rule-of-thumb -

If you have control of the REST API code, then the first one.

If the API has specific validation before reaching the database, dont do the second one unless you plan on copying that code into the consumer. If you want to write directly to a database, then Kafka Connect is the suggested framework for that, not a plain consumer, anyway

If you dont control the API code (its a third-party API), then you are left with option 3

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Just one question, is there any specific reason behihnd this rule of dumb? It seems, by your rule, that the best option is the first one. Why?

Comment: Like I said - you control all the code of the API. Otherwise, you need to speak with some external vendor about adding Kafka support